# Baffling behaviour when summing reciprocals

Tags: excel, sum, excel-2011

I'm trying to quickly compute the sum of reciprocals of several values using Excel 2011 for Mac. Most of the documentation and answers I can find online say it should be as easy as `=SUM(1/rangestart:rangeend)` but I'm getting unexpected results and really weird behaviour from Excel. The only real way I can illustrate it is with a copypasta from Excel to plaintext:

```
    |C1 C2      C3              C4              C5      C6
----+---------------------------------------------------------------
R1  |R  Ohms                                    4       F2
R2  |1  1000    sum(R1:R5)      14500           4       F3
R3  |2  2200    1/sum(R1:R5)    6.90E-05        4       F4
R4  |3  5600    sum(1/R1:R5)    0.000178571     4       F5
R5  |4  1000    1/R1+…+1/R5     0.002845883     #VALUE! sum(1/F2:F5)
R6  |5  4700                                    1       1/F2+…+1/F5
```

Columns 1-4 are in reference to resistors. `SUM(R1:R5)` is if they're in series, and `SUM(1/R1:R5)` should be equal to `1/R1+...+1/R5` as if they're in parallel, but obviously the answers are different. Furthermore, in columns 5 and 6, I tested this with values that would give me a known result as a control experiment, and Excel threw an error with `SUM(1/F2:F5)` instead of a result!

What am I missing to do this the right way in Excel, and what's going on here?

Comment: You need to enter `sum(1/R1:R5)` as an _Array Formula_ (press Ctrl-Shilt-Enter rather than just Enter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @chris neilsen (and for the sake of an answer):

You need to enter `=SUM(1/R1:R5)` as an *Array Formula*

(ie press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> rather than just <kbd>Return</kbd>)